# Do I need to strip tags to improve the search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, full-text-search, solr, sunspot

I am using sunspot with ruby on rails. Its working fine. Contents that are feed into the DB, comes from a rich text editor, so it does have HTML tags. Do I need to strip these tags and just save the content in a separate field in the table. Does using that will improve the accuracy of the search engine.

Answer (score 2):

Stripping tags never hurts; The less noise the better.

You can easily retrieve the text of the document without the tags using Nokogiri:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = <<EOT
<xml>
  <node>This is some text.</node>
  <node>This is more text.</node>
</xml>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
puts doc.text

>> :!ruby test.rb
>> 
>>   This is some text.
>>   This is more text.
>>
```

Nokogiri has options to merge adjacent text nodes but it's easy to do with normal Ruby Array and String manipulation too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use one of the HTML Strip tokenizers in your filter chain (configured in schema.xml):

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.HTMLStripStandardTokenizerFactory

Probably more efficient than adding a parsing step in Nokogiri.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've seen the HTMLStripStandardTokenizerFactory choke and die on malformed markup. Caveat emptor :)